# Mobile-friendly alternative for rollover as CSS sprite

Tags: responsive-design, sprite

CSS rollover sprites were cool, but for responsive design we now use images (which are responsive) rather than CSS backgrounds (which are not). Is there an equivalent to CSS sprites for responsive image-based links ? Or, is there only Javascript for switching from normal state image to hover state image when hovering the link ?

Comment: CSS backgrounds can be responsive using the `background-size` property, but browser support can be a bit of an issue. Worth looking at though.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm the developer of [LazyLou](https://github.com/ozanmuyes/lazylou), I can advise you to use it. It's support for responsive page design as well as pre-loading feature. It might help you.